# Eliminating Discontinuities When Using Mod with NDSolve and Plot for Oscillators

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, discontinuity

I have found similar questions to mine, but dealing with piecewise and parametric plots instead and unfortunately the answers don't seem to extend to my case.

I have a solution from `NDSolve` for two oscillators, however I would like to plot that solution between 0 and 2pi instead of the whole set of reals. I have used `Mod` to keep the values between the desired range, but I am left with the discontinuities you see below. Is there anyway to eliminate these discontinuities for the general case?

Thanks :)

Code to generate solutions:

```
Example[θ1IC0_, θ2IC0_] := 
 Module[{θ1IC = θ1IC0, θ2IC = θ2IC0}, 
  n = 2; 
  ω = {0.95 Ω0, 1.05 Ω0};
  θ = {θ1, θ2};
  Ω0 = (2 π)/24;
  Eqs = Table[θ[[i]]'[t] == ω[[i]] + 1/n Sum[Sin[θ[[j]][t] - θ[[i]][t]], {j, 1, 2}],
         {i, 1, 2}];
  ICs = {θ[[1]][0] == θ1IC, θ[[2]][0] == θ2IC};
  EqsICs = Join[Eqs, ICs];
  {Solution = NDSolve[EqsICs, {θ[[1]], θ[[2]]}, {t, 0, 100}]}]
```

Here is the code to plot the solutions:

```
Show[Table[
  Plot[Mod[θ[[i]][τ] /. Example[0, π/2], 2 π], {τ, 0, 40},
   PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"t", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(θ\), \(i\)]\)"}, 
   PlotStyle -> TwoColours[[i]], 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[{ToString[θ[[i]]]}, Below]],
  {i, 1, 2}]]
```

And here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Note that you haven't defined `TwoColours` in the code you've provided, but that only seems to be necessary for the coloration of the plotted graph.

Comment: Here's a much simpler example that shows the problem you've encountered:  `soln = NDSolve[{x'[t] == 1, x[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 10}];  Plot[Mod[x[t] /. soln, 1], {t, 0, 4}, Exclusions -> "Discontinuities", ExclusionsStyle -> None]`  (Note that adding the `Exclusions` options does not solve the problem.)

Comment: Hey @MichaelSeifert ! Yes, it should be:
TwoColours = {Red, Blue};
Thanks for the catch :)

Comment: Do you want disconnected discontinuities, such as Michael shows below, or do you want to get rid of the discontinuities?  The latter cannot be done using `Mod`, since it is discontinuous.

Comment: Hey other Michael! Just disconnected, I should've been more clear. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for a comment, and it may not be possible to implement this in your code;  but using `NDSolveValue` rather than `NDSolve` appears to make a difference in the following toy example:

```
soln = NDSolve[{x'[t] == 1, x[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 100}]
Plot[Mod[x[t] /. First[soln], 1], {t, 0, 4}, Exclusions -> "Discontinuities", ExclusionsStyle -> None]
```

[image]

```
xsol[t_] = NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == 1, x[0] == 0}, x[t], {t, 0, 100}]
Plot[Mod[xsol[t], 1], {t, 0, 4}, Exclusions -> "Discontinuities", ExclusionsStyle -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: The interesting thing is that the interpolating functions seem identical: `Head[xsol[t]] - (x /. First@soln)`.  But even if you `Evaluate` the `Plot` argument, it still connects the discontinuities.

Comment: Stranger: `Plot[Mod[x[t] /. {x[t] -> xsol[t]}, 1] // Evaluate, {t, 0, 4}, 
 Exclusions -> "Discontinuities", ExclusionsStyle -> None]` connects the discontinuities, even though `NDSolveValue` is used.  Perhaps has to do with `ReplaceAll`?

Comment: Thanks, Michael! Having it work generally, even if it is outside of my original structure, works perfectly for me. My PhD supervisor just wants a few of our results presented like that. Thanks again :)

Comment: `Mod[soln[[1, 1, 2]][t], 1]` with the `NDSolve` code is also plotted sorrectly.

Comment: I posted a question related to this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/193103/4999

Comment: That is interesting that it works with `NDSolve` for that case - I will have to try it out! Thanks, I will take a look at the question :) @MichaelE2