# Evaluation of Mod of InterpolatingFunction prevents discontinuity processing by Plot

Tags: plotting, interpolation, discontinuity

While trying out @MichaelSeifert's answer to [Eliminating Discontinuities When Using Mod with NDSolve and Plot for Oscillators](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/193091/eliminating-discontinuities-when-using-mod-with-ndsolve-and-plot-for-oscillators/193098#193098),
I came across this odd behavior.  Depending on how an `Mod[InterpolatingFunction[t], 1]` is evaluated, the discontinuities of `Mod[]` are connected or not.

```
soln = x -> Interpolation[{#, #}\[Transpose] &@Range[0, 4]];
Plot[Mod[x[t] /. soln, 1], {t, 0, 4}]           (* connected *)
Plot[Mod[soln[[2]][t], 1], {t, 0, 4}]           (* disconnected *)
Plot[Evaluate@Mod[soln[[2]][t], 1], {t, 0, 4}]  (* connected *)
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

The connections persist in the following cases:

- The option `Exclusions -> "Discontinuities"` is given.
- `fn = Mod[soln[[2]][t], 1]` is set and `Plot[fn,..]` is plotted.
- `fn = x[t] /. soln` is set and `Plot[Mod[fn, 1],..]` is plotted.

The discontinuities are disconnected in the following cases:

- `fn = soln[[2]]` is set and `Plot[Mod[fn[t], 1],..]` is plotted.
- `fn = x /. soln` is set and `Plot[Mod[fn[t], 1],..]` is plotted.

I've tried other cases, mainly adding or removing `Evaluate`, but they don't seem worth mentioning.

What is going on? Is there a way to get the discontinuities disconnected in all cases? Does it look like a bug?